# How to aggregate values of a shapefile according to another shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

I have a shapefile that has fine resolution, say 1km by 1km. There are several attributes that I am interested. Let's call this shapefile S1.

I have another shapefile, which is the administrative shapefile, say, all the towns in a state. Let's call this shapefile ST.

ST and S1 have the same spatial span.

So, for a town in ST, there are several pixels in S1 that fall into the town.

I would like to find out the average values of an attribute in all the pixels in S1 that fall into every town in ST.

I tried to Google solutions but I do not know the correct terminology for this type of operation and did not find useful tutorials.

Could you provide some hints or help?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing because you call S1 a shapefile but then say that it has pixels. A shapefile does not have pixels. If S1 is a raster (i.e. an image, or a dataset composed of pixels), you should look into "zonal statistics". Otherwise I would think  an "intersection" of polygons would be the place to start OR you could convert S1 to a raster (this is called "rasterize") and then use zonal statistics.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly, I am terrible at terminologies. S1 is a shapefile with many polygons, which seem to be converted from a raster, somehow. I will try to covert S1 to raster and try zonal statistics!